# Playground string interpolation

Tags: swift, swift-playground, xcode14

Xcode 14, in a playground (with `import UIKit`):

```
let uuid = UUID().uuidString
let boundary = "Boundary-\(uuid)"
```

Fine. But `uuid` isn't really needed, so let's collapse that into a single line:

```
let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
```

That elicits a compile error:

> error: 'UUID' is only available in iOS 6.0 or newer; clients of `'__lldb_expr_9'` may have a lower deployment target

I seem to have riled up the compiler into some weird edge case about how string interpolation works in a playground. What might be going on here?

Comment: And in a macOS Playground (with import Foundation) one gets `error: 'UUID' is only available in macOS 10.8 or newer`

Comment: Strange things also happen in the Swift REPL: `import Foundation ; let uuid = UUID() ` fails with “error: Couldn't lookup symbols” (Xcode 14.1 beta)

Comment: Hi Matt, do you have any update on this?