# Error using localizedDescription in Swift

Tags: swift, error-handling, syntax-error

In the **code below**, I am getting the error :

```
enum errors: Error {
    case too_short, too_obvs
}

func checkPassword(_ passwordEntered: String) throws -> String {
    if passwordEntered.count < 5 {
        throw errors.too_short
    }
    if passwordEntered == "12345" {
        throw errors.too_obvs
    }
    if passwordEntered.count >= 10 {
        return "Password set."
    }
}

let myPassword = "12345"

do {
    let result = try checkPassword(myPassword)
    print("\(result) is your password rating.")
} catch errors.too_short { // customised catch
    print("Password is too short.")
} catch errors.too_obvs {
    print("A 5 yr old would guess that password!")
} catch { // default catch
    print("Error. Enter a stronger password.")
    print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)") // -> to use default Swift error explanations
}
```

**Error -**

> error: value of type 'Error' has no member 'localizedDescription'

```
print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)") // -> to use default Swift error explanations
```

I don't understand why it's pointing out `'Error'` when it isn't even used in the print.

I do not understand what I am missing here. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this in a playground?

Comment: It's possible that you're getting a bogus error because of an error above -- you're missing a return in your `checkPassword` function -- it needs to return from all code paths

Comment: Although I have also seen playgrounds spit out bogus errors for string interpolations. See my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73763834/playground-string-interpolation The workaround is simple, just assign to a variable first.

Comment: @jnpdx there is a return in the function. The last line of the function.

Comment: @matt yes this was playground. However, I typed this is replit too. Same error.

Comment: @HarshDarji A function must return from *all code paths*. You only return if `passwordEntered.count >= 10`. The compiler is giving you an error there.

Comment: Did you look at the link? Repl has the same issue. Just do what I said and don't try this string interpolation in a playground.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, there are idiosyncrasies of Playgrounds. Try the code in an actual app and you will not get that particular error, but rather one pointing out that `checkPassword` is not returning a value for every path of execution.

But to answer the broader question of how one creates localized descriptions for custom error types, one would add [`LocalizedError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/localizederror) conformance:

```swift
enum PasswordError: Error {
    case tooShort
    case tooObvious
}

extension PasswordError: LocalizedError {
    var errorDescription: String? {
        switch self {
        case .tooShort:   return NSLocalizedString("Password is too short", comment: "PasswordError")
        case .tooObvious: return NSLocalizedString("Password is too obvious", comment: "PasswordError")
        }
    }
}
```

And then you have a routine that returns a string for all paths of execution (but you don’t have to have a separate `catch` for each error if you don’t want).

```swift
func passwordRating(_ passwordEntered: String) throws -> String {
    if passwordEntered.count < 5 { throw PasswordError.tooShort }
    if passwordEntered == "12345" { throw PasswordError.tooObvious }

    if passwordEntered.count >= 10 { return "Excellent" }

    return "Acceptable"
}

func validatePassword() {
    do {
        let rating = try passwordRating(myPassword)
        print("\(rating) is your password rating.")
    } catch {
        print("Error. Enter a stronger password.")
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: But `localizedDescription` is guaranteed by the Error protocol. The issue is not the wisdom or otherwise, it's the compile error.

Comment: I totally agree but I repeat, that's irrelevant to the question.

Comment: But that's not the cause of this bogus compile error.

Comment: Correct. I was fixing the bug in the code not trying to address the Playgrounds idiosyncrasies.